# How to Infinite loop an Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on my school project, so i have a library file that is provided to me which scans a code from the card and returns it. The problem is it only works when i press a button. However, i want it to run always and when i scan a card, it will automaticly return the card id without pressing the button.

It gets the card value partially, card id is totally 16 characters but it takes 3-4 characters at a time. So it is like:

### id=10 id=2310 id=632010 .... id = 123434233632010

And when there is no card, it returns null.

How can i create a asynctask that runs in background and scans infinitely? And when the code is 16 characters, it stops the task and starts a new activity?

Edit:

```
    public class TestService extends IntentService {

    public int handle, type = 0x26;
    MediaReader md = new MediaReader();
    String cardId;

    public TestService() {
        super("TestService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                cardId = "";
                int ret = md.CardPoll(type);
                if (ret == 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < md.uid_len; i++) {

                        cardId = cardId + md.uid[i];
                    }
                    Log.e("MyLogs", cardId);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("deneme", "No card detected");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `AsyncTask`, despite to popular beliefs, is not intended to be run indefinitely and really shouldn't be. `AsyncTask` is meant to do short tasks that requires some effort or even network operations, and after, they just end.

If you're looking to run a loop indefinitely and you want to do it in background, I suggest using a background `Service`. This doesn't provide a `Thread` as `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method does, but you can create one yourself.

As it is a `Service`, you'll need to handle it accordingly and always use `startService()` and `stopService()` when needed, otherwise even if your app is closed it might still be running when it's not needed (which is not a good practice).

Comment: After defining my Service, how can i get it to loop?

Comment: Simply define a loop inside as if you were doing anywhere else. I recommend defining your loop within a `Thread` inside you `Service`, as infinite loops shouldn't be defined in the main thread. I also recommend sleeping (`Thread.sleep(...)`) whenever possible, at least for a short amount of time.

Comment: Okay done! Can you check my code and see if its good enough? I edited it on main post.

Comment: Seems ok to me, this should be a way.

Comment: And what is a good way to change a textview in main activity with the values from this service?

Comment: You should probably use a local `BroadcastReceiver` or an `Handler` to make the values be sent to your `Activity` and update it from there. You cannot update this values directly from the `Service`. There are thousands of examples on both if you search in google.

Comment: So outta curiosity, what's wrong with running an infinite loop inside doInBackground of AsyncTask?